# Can (nx) feature libraries access the global state?

Tags: ngrx, nrwl-nx

According to the Nx Docs, features of an application should still be moved into libraries. Of course, I can add feature-level state to each of these libraries, but what if there is a property on the global AppState that I would like to access from a feature library? I cannot import anything from the apps/ directory.

Is there a way to share state with feature libraries or should I move my features back into the apps/ directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround has been to avoid a global store state. Instead, I create a dedicated, componentless module defining the `forFeature()` state, selectors, reducers, effects, etc. I then export all those from the dedicated module using forRoot().

Now I can import this dedicated feature state module into independent application feature modules. As @satanTime points out, this state is not duplicated or replaced since it is added to the global state via `forFeature()`.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that there are *feature* reducers and selectors.

However, it is important to understand that there is **no feature store**.

There is only **one global store** which has state for all the reducers.
Therefore *feature* reducers and selectors work with the global store and global state and can fully access it.

For example, if two different modules call `StoreModule.forFeature('test', testReducer)` - both modules share the state, although it might give an impression that every module has own `test` feature state.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a question specifically about nrwl's nx monorepo structure.

Comment: If it uses ngrx - the statement is still true.

Comment: What would you like to complete?

Comment: unfortunately it is not correct. Any feature module has access to global state, without having a parent `.forRoot` call a `.forFeature` module would fail. There is nothing to do with `nx`, it is how `ngrx` works in Angular.

Comment: If the question is not about a property in the state, but about importing in a lib reducers and selectors from an app, then okay - it is a different subject and it is about how to use nx. It wasn't clearly mentioned in the question.

Comment: It is the latter. I edited my question to improve clarity